# Fatal Exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException length=10; index=-1

Tags: android

```
   if(!settingsResponse.isEmpty()) {
                        String[] parts = settingsResponse.substring(settingsResponse.indexOf("FR")).split("P_");
                        String front = "", in = "", rear = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                            String part = parts[i].replace("\"", "").replace("P", "").replace(";", "").trim().replace(" ", ""); // 004
                            if (part.contains("FR")) {
                                front = part;
                            } else if (part.contains("IN")) {
                                in = part;
                            } else if (part.contains("R")) {
                                rear = part;
                            }
                            Log.i("TAG", "onChanged111: " + part);
                        }

                        Log.i("TAG", "onChanged111: " + selectedPosition);

                        if (front.equals("FR2160") && in.equals("") && rear.equals("")) {
                            selectedPosition = 0;
                        } else if (front.equals("FR1520") && in.equals("") && rear.equals("")) {
                            selectedPosition = 1;

                        } else if (front.equals("FR1440") && in.equals("") && rear.equals("")) {
                            selectedPosition = 2;

                        } else if (front.equals("FR1080") && in.equals("") && rear.equals("")) {
                            selectedPosition = 3;

                        } else if (front.equals("FR720") && in.equals("") && rear.equals("")) {
                            selectedPosition = 4;

                        }
                    }
```

at line   String[] parts = settingsResponse.substring(settingsResponse.indexOf("FR")).split("P_");

I am getting Fatal Exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=10; index=-1 even i have added setting is not empty then i dont know why this crash is coming please help me how to fix this crash.

Comment: According to your code and exception: `settingsResponse` doesn't contain "FR". you need to decide how to handle such case.

Comment: The fact that it's not empty does not mean that it contains "FR"

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel thanks for your answer  suppose if some case if in settingResponse does not contain FR then i dont need to execute any code we have display some thing went wrong then do we need add condition before  settingsResponse.substring(settingsResponse.indexOf("FR")).split("P_"); or after  can you please suggest me ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your exceptional case, `settingsResponse` was not empty, but still did not contain "FR", which leads to exception.

I suggest handling `settingsResponse` without "FR" the same way you handle empty response.

Simply replace this:

```
if (!settingsResponse.isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

With this:

```
if (settingsResponse.contains("FR")) {
    ...
}
```

No need to check for emptiness since `settingsResponse` definitely non-empty if it contains "FR"